# If $f(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}$ , then find $f^{1991}(2+i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $f(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}$ , then find $f^{1991}(2+i)$

Forgive me if the question is too short but really I don't know how to do this one.

That's what I have done so far:

$\left(f(2+i)\right)^{1991}=\left(\cfrac{3+i}{1+i}\right)^{1991}$

So now If I can find a polar form for $(3+i)$ and $(1+i)$ I can  then apply the property that for any complex number I have $(s,\phi)^{1991}=(s^{1991},1991 \cdot\phi)$

The problem is that I can't find one,and by checking with [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%283%2Bi%29%2F%281%2Bi%29%29%5E1991) I've understood why.

Therefore there must be slick way I am not seeing.

Can you guys help ?

Comment: You have a notation misconception:  By $f^n(u)$ they mean $f(f^{n-1}(u))$, not $[f(u)]^n$.

Comment: Oh.Thanks for that....so my effort is totally flawed.

Comment: If you don't see the 'trick' then there are other ways to get the result. The transformation is a so-called [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). Such a transformation can be decomposed in terms of elementary transformations as: $\frac{z+1}{z-1} = [z + 1] \circ [2z] \circ [1/z] \circ [z - 1]$ which is a “translation by $1$” + “dilation by $2$” + “inversion” + “translation by $-1$”. In this picture (when you get some intuition) not too hard to see that applying it two times should give you back what you started with so $f\circ f = z$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$ f^2(z) = \frac{\frac{z+1}{z-1}+1}{\frac{z+1}{z-1}-1} = z $$
So $f^{2k}(z) = z$ and $f^{2k+1}(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$

$$f^{1991}(2+i) = \frac{3+i}{1+i} = 2-i$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Check that $f^2(z)=z$. What can you deduce from this relation?

Comment: I see what you mean,but now I am curious :why it does work for every even power?

Comment: Because any power of identity is identity.

Comment: Because $f^{2n}(z) = [f^2]^n(z)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Where can I find a usefull resource about that ?I don't really get much from a comment (I need to see all the theory behind ...)

Comment: @Mr Y: There's no real theory: it's just the laws of exponents which is the same for the composition of a function with itself and for a number. Now, I think it is obvious that $\;f^{2n}(z)=\bigl(f^2\bigr)^n(z)=(\operatorname{id})^n(z)=\operatorname{id}(z)=z$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1} \Rightarrow f(f(z))=f^2(z)=z$

Similarly $f^3(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}$

So proceeding in this manner we get , $f^{2n}(z)=z$ and $f^{2n+1}(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}$

So $f^{1991}(z)=\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}$

Therefore $f^{1991}(2+i)=\cfrac{3+i}{1+i}=2-i$